# Adjust GeoTIFF symbology in QGIS to look accurate

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

Here I have a GeoTIFF which I know isn't displaying properly because it is meant to be topography. What am I doing wrong? I want the tops of the hills to be light colour and the valleys be darker. This has been converted to a GeoTIFF from a gxf via Geosoft viewer.

[image]

Comment: You have min/max values from 0 to 255 - to me, this doesn't look like topography (elevantion), at least not in the form of a DEM (Digital Elevation Model). You should provide more information about the file and where you have it from , maybe even sharing it.

Comment: Hi @Babel, it is definietely a DEM of some sort, because when I import it into geosoft viewer as a gxf (I can't import it into QGIS as a GXF for some reason, so I imported it to geosoft then exported it as a tiff), I can see the hills and valleys, also the file name is called "terr". In geosoft I can see that the pixel values range up to 1300, but when I open up information in QGIS of the geotiff it says that each band has a max of 255. I can't upload this unfortunately as it is client held private data. thanks for your help

Comment: So the real problem in fact is another one: how to correctly export your DEM (if it really is one) from Geosoft/GXF to TIFF/QGIS. You should change your question accordingly and describe in detail how you export it (settings etc.).

Comment: Hi @Babel here is the new question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/458256/how-to-export-raster-from-geosoft-viewer-and-import-to-qgis

Comment: Did you try importing to QGIS using Data Source Manager? You can choose GeoSoft Grid Exchange Format. If not: what kind of output formats and output parameters do you have in Geosoft? Maybe you can add this as a screenshot? In any way, you should export as single bad - thus not color.

Comment: Hi @Babel, it worked! I don't know why I couldn't import it into QGIS before - I tried drag and drop and also select raster via Data Source manager, but this time I imported via Data Source Manager and selected the specific .gxf format and it imported as a single band greyscale image straight away the first time. Thank you very much for your help, I spent way too long trying to figure this out!

Comment: "I select outfput format as GeoTIFF COLOUR" -> Are there other options? Surely you want to export it as DATA, not as a colourful image only.

Answer (score 2):

Use Data Source manager to import your file: in the import dialog, you can choose GeoSoft Grid Exchange Format.

[image]