# Export raster from Geosoft viewer and Import to QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, geosoft

I am having trouble exporting a raster from Geosoft viewer and importing it into QGIS and displaying it properly. Here I have a .gxf file dtm, which for some reason I can't import into QGIS (it just says this file type is not supported). I import it into geosoft viewer via >Grids>Open Grids, and it looks like the image on the left. I then then export by right clicking the file (I have also tried via the Export>Copy/Convert Grids tab) and clicking copy/convert. I select outfput format as GeoTIFF COLOUR, and when I import it to QGIS (drag and drop, or import>raster), it seems to lose some of the elevation data and looks like the one on the right.

I have tried exporting as a geosoft colour grid, geosoft default grid, ER Mapper RGB Colour (* .ers) and geopack grid, and these don't import into QGIS. When I try export to ER Mapper (* .ers) and ER mapper ECW Compressor (*.ecw) it asks me to locate the file - the select "output folder" is greyed out and not sure why I can't export to these two file types.

You can see in the below image that the original dtm ratser has values that go up to 1251, but when I import into QGIS as a geotiff the values for each band only go up to 255. I am not sure why this is. Is there another free software I can use to convert raster types so that they are compatible with QGIS? Can anyone please help?

Original question: [How to adjust geotiff symbology in QGIS to look accurate](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/458248/how-to-adjust-geotiff-symbology-in-qgis-to-look-accurate)

*I can't upload the file as it is privately held data*

*QGIS version 3.22.15*

[image]